# C++ setting a pointer to another pointer

Tags: c++

```
Object* a = new Object();

Object* b = a;
```

Is there a way in the Object class to know that 'b = a' happened? I tried overloading the operator= but it didn't seem to fire.

Comment: Why not just use `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Because I'm just playing around with this idea and was wondering if C++ informed me of this operation happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overloaded the operator for Object not for Object*. You cannot overload operators for primitive pointers.

You will need to write a wrapper that simulates pointers but tracks operations. Perhaps you're looking for a smart pointer like shared_ptr? It implements reference counting like it seems you're trying to do.

Comment: Bummer. I am looking for a smart pointer but I don't like wrapping pointers so was playing with possible alternatives. So no way to know when one pointer is set to another huh? That sucks. Thanks.

Comment: Oh is that actually true about not being able to overload operator = for Object*? I thought that was possible?

Comment: @user441521 Not realistically. A wrapper is your only reasonable option. Luckily the wrapper can be fairly transparent since * and -> can be overloaded to act on the wrapped pointer.

Comment: I don't see why you need to know when the assignment happens?

Comment: @paulm An object must be one of the operands. Primitive/primitive operators cannot be overloaded. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/intrinsics-and-operator-overloading.html

Comment: @Corbin, what do you mean reasonable option? Is it possible in C++? I don't like defining the pointers as a template and I don't like defining function params as the template when I need to pass them around. As a personal preference I think it looks crappy and just curious if this is possible.

Comment: @user441521 It's not possible in standard C++. The only way you could do it would be to instrument the executable produced to handle it. Basically you would have to build on to whatever compiler you're using to tell it to put some extra tracking code around every pointer assignment. It's *technically* possible, but it would be *highly* unpleasant and not very maintainable.

Comment: @user441521 As for the ugliness of smartpointers... Unfortunately that's just the way it is to a large extent. I agree with you that they're ugly to pass around. The passing around should be fairly minimal though. And if you don't care about the smart semantics, every smart pointer I've ever seen exposes the raw pointer so you can use it directly.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that pointers are easy to overuse in C++ if you're not careful. You might want to step back at some point, decide why you're using a shared pointer and decide if it's correct. A shared pointer should only be used if multiple objects truly do own (as in are responsible for it's life cycle) one object.  That tends to be a fairly rare situation in most programs. If you're just using smart pointers for easy life time management, than automatic lifetime (i.e. variables on the stack) and RAII are probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really what you want to do?

Seems to me that you want to copy  the value of a to b?

I.e:

```
Object* b = *a;
```

Otherwise you are just setting b to point to a. You'd have to overload operator = for Object* rather than operator = as part of Object for a const Object&. Unless you really do want to copy the pointer in which case what you have is fine.

Note that overloading operator = for Object* is aparrently not possible! I doubt this is actually what you where really trying to do anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to invoke the copy constructor of Object class or use the '=' operator of Object class. It's just the assignment between two pointers of Object. So even you has overload the Object's '=' operator, which is not invoked in this case, you got nothing fired.